# iOS Facebook Login helper sdk like Parser

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently RayWenderlich has published a tutorial on integrating facebook on ios app
http://www.raywenderlich.com/44640/integrating-facebook-and-parse-tutorial-part-1

With the use of Parse SDK it makes it really easy to use Facebook login in your app 
like in App Delegate you just need to add

```
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"<your_parse_app_id>" clientKey:@"<your_parse_client_key>"];

    // Initialize Parse's Facebook Utilities singleton. 
    // This uses the FacebookAppID we specified in our App bundle's plist.
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
    return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
```

And for login button

```
[Comms login:self];
```

The problem is that for Parse to work you must have a Parse account 
What I am searching is for framework like Parse where facebook logoin is made easy with code blocks like

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:nil block:^(PFUser *user,
NSError *error) { ... }
```

Q1. Is there any other framework that provide such ease to use Facebook SDK ?

Q2. Can we use ParseSDK for facebook logoin without using its online service ?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: StackMob and Azure Mobile Services both offer similar APIs.

Q2: No. Those methods will store data to the Parse user tables. Same goes with StackMob and Azure.

If the Facebook SDK is too complicated for you, use the Accounts Framework provided in iOS. It provides super easy block based methods to login (use `requestAccessToAccountsWithType`). There are plenty of examples on SO for how to use it.